# migrating mysql to mysqli in ajax environment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, mysqli

First i would like to say thank you for letting me ask questions again. I know my previous question was a bit low level of knowledge. Today, I would like to ask if the principle of converting mysql to mysqli in ajax is same with html. Suppose this is my Connect.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "765632";
$dbname = "student";
$link_id = mysqli_connect($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link_id)); 
?>
```

and my ajax.php is

```
<?php
  //Connect to MySQL Server

include 'Connect.php';
mysql_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
//Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
 // Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['first_name']));
// Retrieve data from Query  
$query = "SELECT  student_id, LRN, first_name, last_name, grade, section  FROM student_information WHERE first_name LIKE '%{$first_name}%'";     
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 //Generate the output
$searchResults = '';
if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
```

What are the changes should i made to convert it to mysqli without changing its logical scheme.

Comment: 1) read the php manual regarding mysqli. 2) Google for "migrating mysql to mysqli". 3) read this [tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-convert-mysqli-functions-to-mysql-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
$link_id = mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
//Select Database
mysqli_select_db($link_id, $dbname) or die(mysqli_error($link_id));
// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link_id, trim($_GET['first_name']));
// Retrieve data from Query
$query = "SELECT  student_id, LRN, first_name, last_name, grade, section  FROM student_information WHERE first_name LIKE '%{$first_name}%'";
$result = mysqli_query($link_id, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link_id));
//Generate the output
$searchResults = '';
if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
```

Comment: Don't call `mysqli_real_escape_string` manually, you're liable to make a mistake and introduce a horrendous [SQL injection bug by accident](http://bobby-tables.com/). Instead use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and placeholders.

Comment: @tadman i wonder if you could help me how to use the suggested bind_param and placeholder in accordance to my given codes.

Comment: @user3659034 Thannk you so much, It works without affecting the logical schema. The question has been solved